# create-react-app is unable to create app. It just creates package.json, package-lock.json and node modules and gets stuck at as shown below:

Tags: reactjs

$ create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\devar\Desktop\test-react\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\devar\Desktop\test-react\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\devar\Desktop\test-react\my-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\devar\Desktop\test-react\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

- cra-template@1.0.3
- react-scripts@3.4.1
- react@16.13.1
- react-dom@16.13.1
  added 1607 packages from 750 contributors and audited 1611 packages in 60.007s

65 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: It isn't recommended to install CRA locally/globally, just `npx create-react-app my-app` so it grabs latest. Also ensure your environment meets requirements: `Node >= 8.10` and `npm >= 5.6`.

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure you have Node.js installed:

https://nodejs.org/en/

Be sure to choose LTS version (12.8.3 at the time of writing).

Run `node -v`, it should display a version higher than 8.10

Run `npm -v`, it should display a version higher than 5.6

## Install app using NPX

If you're wondering where did **NPX** come from:

> NPX comes bundled with NPM version 5.2+

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Comment: I already have node version 12.18.3 and npm version 6.14.6. And here the strange thing is I've already created many react apps but in my new laptop only it's giving this issue.